# HTML 5 Draw Arc Based On Given Time

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Can you please help me to figure out how to calculate following js script to display the reminding amount of total(instead of percentage)?
For example if the total(given) is **90** and also `current` is **90** then the whole arc will be drawn and if the current amount is `45` the half of the arc must be drawn.

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');

var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
var context = can.getContext('2d');

var given;
var current;

var percentage = .5; 
var degrees = percentage * 360;
var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var r = 30;
var s = 1.5 * Math.PI;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,50,30,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();



context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 10;

context.arc(x, y, r, s, radians+s, false);
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of finding the proper value for your existing `percentage` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had to change the `var percentage`. Now it works, set your `current` and `given` as you please.

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');

var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
var context = can.getContext('2d');

var given = SET YOUR GIVEN VALUE;
var current = SET YOUR CURRENT VALUE;

var percentage = current/given; 
var degrees = percentage * 360;
var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var r = 30;
var s = 1.5 * Math.PI;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,50,30,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();



context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 10;

context.arc(x, y, r, s, radians+s, false);
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```